# Rails redirect after first login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise for authorization.

What I want is that after the user signs in for the first time, he is redirected to a page where he has to complete his profile before continuing to the main application

Can you please tell me how to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want is that after the user signs in for the first time, he is
>   redirected to a page where he has to complete his profile before
>   continuing to the main application

Devise provides a column called `sign_in_count` which gets updated when a user signs in. You can use this in `after_sign_in_path_for` to achieve what you wanted. In the `application_controller` add the below

```
#application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.sign_in_count == 1
    redirect_to #your custom path here
  else
    # your code
  end
end
```